# How to change the description of textbox widgets depending on the chosen option of a dropdown widget? (Dictionary of Lists)

Tags: list, dictionary, widget, ipython, jupyter

I desire to change the description of textbox widgets depending on the chosen option of a dropdown widget. I thought I could achieve this by using a dictionary of lists. This is an example of what I did:

```
#Lists of text box descriptions
LEF_SOL = ['AMP','DEP','LAGTIME']
INI_SOL = ['AMP','DEP','XWavemaker']
INI_REC = ['Xc','Yc','WID']

# dictionary made with such lists
wave_options = {'left boundary solitary':LEF_SOL, 
            'initial solitary wave':INI_SOL,'rectangular hump':INI_REC}

#dropdown widget of the dictionary
wave_maker = widgets.Dropdown(options=wave_options)

# Textbox 1 description = first object of list depending on the dropdown 
first_option = widgets.BoundedFloatText(width = "20%",height = '50px',
                           description = wave_maker.value[0])

# Textbox 2 description = second object of list depending on the dropdown 
second_option = widgets.BoundedFloatText(width = "20%",height = '50px',
                           description = wave_maker.value[1])

# Textbox 3 description = third object of list depending on the dropdown
third_option = widgets.BoundedFloatText(width = "20%",height = '50px',
                           description = wave_maker.value[2])

display(wave_maker,first_option,second_option,third_option)
```

Yet when I run this, the textboxes descriptions stay being the ones belonging to the first option that appears in the dropdown. I want them to change if the dropdown is changed. I know that this can be done with 'link'. It should look something like this:

```
link((wave_maker,'value[0]'), (first_option, 'description'))
link((wave_maker,'value[1]'), (second_option, 'description'))
link((wave_maker,'value[2]'), (third_option, 'description'))
```

Yet an error occurs:

```
TypeError: <ipywidgets.widgets.widget_selection.Dropdown
object at   0x7fd47bbbd790> has no trait 'value[0]'
```

Yet when I change the 'link' to:

```
link((wave_maker,'value'), (first_option, 'description'))
```

then this error appears:

```
TraitError: The 'description' trait of a BoundedFloatText
instance must be a unicode string, but a value of ['AMP', 'DEP',   'XWavemaker']
 <type 'list'> was specified.
```

Is there a way I could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution to my question can be done by using the traitlets "observe" or "interact". I've attached an "observe" example:

```
wave_options = ('INI_SOL', 'WK_IRR')
int_range = widgets.Dropdown(options=wave_options)
Xc_WK = widgets.BoundedFloatText()
DEP_WK = widgets.BoundedFloatText()

display(int_range,Xc_WK,DEP_WK)

def on_value_change(value):
    if int_range.value == 'WK_IRR':
        Xc_WK.description = 'Xc_WK'
        DEP_WK.description='DEP_WK'

    else:
        Xc_WK.description ='amp'
        DEP_WK.description='DEP'


int_range.observe(on_value_change, 'value')
```